# Vue wait until all images referenced in CSS have loaded

Tags: vue.js

In my Vue app I have a large image (170K) that is referenced in CSS as a background image. While my app is initially loading, I would like to show a spinner image or div that waits until this image has finished loading. This seems to be the default behavior in Angular2+, how do I achieve the same with Vue?

CSS looks like this:

```
.hero-image {
  background-image: url(../assets/images/bigimage.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px -150px;
  background-size: 1920px 1080px;  
}
```

EDIT:
So far I have tried the following and it did not work. HTML/CSS/Component still loads before that background image has finished loading:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
  })
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Answer (score 0):

Try this without the listener

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App v-cloack />',
    components: { App }
  })
```